# Does setState rebuild the whole widget tree for a screen in flutter and how does it compare with other State management

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, state-management

I'm kinda confused, I have been looking into state management with flutter recently and I was wondering what happens if a custom stateful widget is placed in a stateless widget, let's say widgetA (parent) is a stateless widget and it has a child WidgetB which is a stateful widget and another child WidgetC which is a stateless widget.

Now my questions are:

- if setState() is called from widgetB, are WidgetA, B, and C rebuilt?
- how does this compare to using different state Management techniques like State provider, stream builders, or Bloc?
- when to use setState()?
- is it smart to combine multiple State management techniques?

**if you have external links or resources that can help me understand please provide them**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I say something wrong, someone please correct me.

Answering your questions in order:

1. If you call `setState()` on `WidgetB` it'll rebuild itself and it's descendants, no matter if they are `Stateless` or `Stateful` Widgets.
2. Using the **BLoC** approach, most of the times it's optional to use `Stateful Widgets` and `setState()` to manage State. In this approach you'll use `events` from the *UI*, which will be converted into 'States' inside your BLoC. This States will be passed into a Stream. Your *UI* will rebuild itself using `StreamBuilders` every time they listen to a new value on the Stream they're listening. This will trigger the `StreamBuilder` to rebuilt itself and it's descendants.
3. If you're using `BLoC` or `Provider`  + `Streams`, I would recommend avoiding `setState()` and `StatefulWidgets`, maybe with some exceptions like UI things, eg. animations.
4. BLoC is a design approach with goes nice with the `Provider package`. The `BLoC package` even uses `Provider` internally.

P.S.: Whereas `BLoC` is an Architecture Pattern to manage the Data and State of your application. Provider is 'just' a wrapper around `Inherited Widgets` that facilitate exposure of Data throughout your Widget tree, not an Architecture Pattern.

Other example of architecture pattern solution to manage state that uses the `provider` package is `MobX`.

Comment: In number 4, "The BLoC package even uses Provider internally.", this might cause people to think that the bloc package uses provider to handle the state; While it's not that way and It uses provider only to provide a bloc to the widget tree.

Comment: @AliAlizadeh just added this comment to make it clearer

Comment: In number 1, descendants or children with `const` prefix will not rebuild if`setState` is called on the parent. However, if you remove the `const` prefix it will rebuild that child widget.

Answer (score 3):

setState() will call the build() method and rebuilds with widget tree (With Flutter optimizations under the hood), if you wish to build only a part there is an Alternative: create a Provider that holds the change that you want to reflect in the UI, and wrap that widget with a Consumer - when you will call notifyListener() from the Provider only that Widget will rebuild.

For Example:

```
 child: Consumer<MessageIconStateProvider>(
        builder: (context, messageIconProvider, child) {
          return Container(
            height: 40,
            child: messageIconProvider.isShowMessageIcon
                ? Icon(
              Icons.send,
              size: 24,
              color: Colors.white,
            )
                : Icon(
              Icons.mic_outlined,
              size: 24,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          );
        }
    )
```

The provider:

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MessageIconStateProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  var isShowMessageIcon = true;
  
  void setIconToMessage(bool setIconToMessage){
    if(setIconToMessage != isShowMessageIcon) {
      isShowMessageIcon = setIconToMessage;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }


}
```

And don't forget to define it on your main.dart file:

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => MessageIconStateProvider()),
      ],...
```

Comment: When you say “only that Widget will rebuild” does it mean _only_ that widget (and not any descendant Widgets) or “only the Widget tree from that node down”?